# Fixed Height for overview-box

Tags: html, css

[image: Sample Of The Problem]

I would like to fix the height of each box while using this style.

Here is my CSS and HTML code for this overview-boxes for reference. Probably you will not get the same UI as mine, picture that I put is what I am trying to fix.

If the span gets longer values box height automatically increases. I would like to prevent that outcome while still using this format of overview-items

```css
.ohs-text-overview h2{
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.ohs-text-overview span{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
/* ----- Overview ----- */
.ohs-overview-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .ohs-overview-wrap {
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -moz-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .ohs-overview-wrap .button {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -webkit-order: 1;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
        order: 1;
    }

    .ohs-overview-wrap h2 {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
        -webkit-order: 2;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
        -ms-flex-order: 2;
        order: 2;
    }
}

.ohs-overview-item {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1519px) {
    .ohs-overview-item {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
}

.ohs-overview-item--c1 {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #3f5efb 0%, #fc466b 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #3f5efb 0%, #fc466b 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #3f5efb 0%, #fc466b 100%);
}

.ohs-overview-item--c2 {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #11998e 0%, #38ef7d 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #11998e 0%, #38ef7d 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #11998e 0%, #38ef7d 100%);
}

.ohs-overview-item--c3 {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #ee0979 0%, #ff6a00 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #ee0979 0%, #ff6a00 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #ee0979 0%, #ff6a00 100%);
}

.ohs-overview-item--c4 {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #45b649 0%, #dce35b 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #45b649 0%, #dce35b 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #45b649 0%, #dce35b 100%);
}

.ohs-overview-box .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.ohs-overview-box .icon i {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .ohs-overview-box .icon {
        margin-right: 3px;
    }

    .ohs-overview-box .icon i {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .ohs-overview-box .icon {
        font-size: 46px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row m-t-25" id="corrective_action_summary_ii" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="col-md">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="ohs-overview-item ohs-overview-item--c2">
      <div class="ohs-overview__inner">
        <div class="ohs-overview-box clearfix">
          <div class="ohs-text-overview">
            <h2>1</h2>
            <span>Action Will Described</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="ohs-overview-item ohs-overview-item--c2">
      <div class="ohs-overview__inner">
        <div class="ohs-overview-box clearfix">
          <div class="ohs-text-overview">
            <h2>1</h2>
            <span>Action Is In Progress</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="ohs-overview-item ohs-overview-item--c2">
      <div class="ohs-overview__inner">
        <div class="ohs-overview-box clearfix">
          <div class="ohs-text-overview">
            <h2>0</h2>
            <span>Action Completed</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a read of https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/ This allows you to resize the text to fit whatever container it's in

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, If I understand correctly this is not what I am trying to achieve. I don't want my text to change its size, I want my box height to have a fixed value.

Comment: try adding `max-height: 150px;` to `.ohs-overview-item`

Comment: Thank you not max but min-height solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ohs-overview-item {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: 120px;
}
```

adding min-height has solved my problem thanks to [gpl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13828124/gpl)